# get data from two different cores in solr

Tags: solr, solrj

i have two different-different core i want join and get all fields from both core as mysql inner join does.

**Core Product :**

```
product_id
product_details
author_id
```

**Core Author:**

```
 author_id
    author_name
    author_detail
```

i need all fields from both core with joining using `author_id`. i have tried with join but it will return me data from one core either `product` or `author` or need to make two query and combine dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Solr joins are not able to retrieve information from both sides of the join - they're only able to filter by a value on the other side, not retrieve the information.

You'll have to either structure the documents as suitable for [block joins](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers), or make two queries - first retrieve the content on one side of the join, then fetch all the documents that match on the other side. This might be the most flexible and quickest solution, and will scale well (as the other lookup is just on the joined field as `field:(foo OR bar OR baz)` after iterating through the first set).

A third option is to just index the author_name and author_detail together with your core products. As long as those values isn't present in a million documents and changes every second, the performance will be fine.